# How can I get the ID of an item in a radio-group in a helper.form?

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I am building some sort of quiz where the user gets a question and several possible answers. The answers are listed within a radio-group and could be **duplicates**!

Example:

```
How tall is tall?
- Very!
- Depends on your definition!
- Very!
```

The questions and answers come from a list and are saved in a database. 
Depending on if the user has clicked the correct answer, the answer then gets a new score.

My problem now is: I can get the text of the clicked radio-button, but cant get / see the ID of the matching answer in the controller. How can I do that?

**quiz.scala.html:**

```
@import models.Question
@import models.Answer

@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._

@(questionList: List[Question], answerList: List[Answer], answerRadioForm: Form[Answer])
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.nextQuizPage(), 'id -> "answerRadioForm"){
            <fieldset>
                @helper.inputRadioGroup(
                answerRadioForm("Answer"),
                options = answerList.map(answer => answer.answerText.toString -> answer.answerText),
                '_label -> "answer",
                '_error -> answerRadioForm("Answer").error.map(_.withMessage("select answer"))
                )
            </fieldset>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Send">
            Next question
        </button>
```

The user clicks on a radio button and in the controller I bind the answer from the form:

**Application.java:**

```
Form<Answer> filledForm = answerForm.bindFromRequest();
// I try to find the answerID my matching the answerText, 
// which is really unreliable - think of 2 answers with the same answerText ...
List<Answer> findAnswerList = Answer.find
                                    .where()
                                    .like("answer_text", filledForm.data().get("Answer").toString())
                                    .findList();
```

**Answer.java (in models):**

```
@Entity
public class Answer extends Model implements Comparable<Answer>{
    // The questionID is needed to somehow link the answer to a question, as an answer can not be without one
    @Id
    public String answerID;
    public String questionID;
    public String answerText;
    public Integer voteScore;
    public String ownerID;
    public Integer page;
}
```

I have tried to append an ID field to the helper-form:
`'_id -> answer.answerID` but I get the error saying that "answer" is not known.

So, any ideas how I can transfer the answerID to the controller? Or see / get it otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that your input options have a unique value as the helper generates the input IDs as "Classname_value" automatically and uses the value-attribute for the form submission. In your example this would result in two input fields with an id_attribute "Answer_Very!" and identical value-attributes as you are using the answerText as the value and not only as the label.

Try changing the key of your options Sequence which translates to the value-attribute of the input element to something unique like `answer.answerID`

```
 @helper.inputRadioGroup(
      answerRadioForm("Answer"),
      options = answerList.map(answer => answer.answerID -> answer.answerText)
 )
```

Comment: Thanks, making sure the input is unique would be pretty hard to accomplish in my case. In the quiz users can answer questions, so the input get generated dynamically by people. I would have to catch every variation of the same answer (very, Very, very., Very!, VERY!, ...) while it also contains normal language. But using the ID helps me alot, so I can filter out whats a wrong / correct answer, which is what I need for my quiz.